# "Listen along" feature in discord and spotify for a bot

Tags: discord, spotify

I'm working on a Discord bot and I want it to mimic whatever I'm playing on Discord. I'm aware that Discord has a "listen along with another person" feature. I want to take advantage of this feature. Just wondering if there's any way to do the same using a bot instead of my own discord account, so instead of clicking the "Listen along" button on my account, people can click that button on the bot's account.